# Is this valid optimization?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

`"Hello."` is a temporary that's constructed, copied into `std::string` and subsequently destroyed. We can skip copying and go straight to moving. But any decent compiler will elide the copy. So is there any point to the following:

```
std::string s(std::move("Hello."));
```

Comment: Makes it harder to read

Comment: Just because the answer is no doesn't make it a bad question

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no point moving a string literal. It's a static array (*not* a "temporary that's constructed"), which can't be moved, only copied.

Answer (score 0):

If that's even legal and I don't know if it is, it is not optimising anything.

The literal is created at compile time in static space. It can't be moved. `string` will always own a copy of the data and not just "refer" to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense as it would be logically equal to this:

```
Foo bar( std::move( 123 ) );
```

There is no point to move constant, and string literal is a constant. Better question would be, and I think is that what you really meant by your question:

```
class Foo { ... };

class Bar {
public:
    Bar( const Foo &foo );
    Bar( Foo &&foo );
...
};

Bar bar( std::move( Foo() ); // Does it make sense?
```

So actually for this case `std::move` can be used as a syntax sugar to avoid function declaration of the form:

```
Bar bar( Foo() );
```

But it would not make any optimization and in this case:

```
Bar bar = std::move( Foo() );
```

It would be completely redundant

Comment: Actually, `Bar bar( std::move( Foo() );` *does* make sense, because `Bar bar( Foo() );` is just a function declaration :)

Comment: How about `Bar bar = Foo();` simpy? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow how about you read the answer, see that `std::move()` is completely redundant in the last statement and remove `std::move()` from there?